# Could not click a button in popup e2e

Tags: angular, protractor, ionic2

I have a button inside a popup in .ts file, I need to click that button and execute some action,

```
accept() {
        let prompt              =   Alert.create({
            title               :   'Accepted',
            cssClass            :   'accepted',
            enableBackdropDismiss               :     false,
            buttons: [{
                text            :   'Accept',
                cssClass        :   'button1',
                handler         :   data        =>  {
                    this.approveForm();
                }
            },{
                text            :   'Cancel',
                cssClass        :   'button3',
                id              :   'cancel',
                handler         :   data        =>  {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }]
        });

        this.nav.present(prompt);
    }
```

i tried using its id terminal says no element found
i tried with button text

```
it('should open the accept and reject popup click cancel button',() => {
        acceptPopup.click();    
        element(by.buttonText('CANCEL')).click();
        browser.driver.sleep(6000);     
    });
```

but still i get err

```
✗ should open the accept and reject popup click cancel button
      - Failed: No element found using locator: by.buttonText("CANCEL")
F
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that your popup opens asynchronously and it's not visible right away. Try to wait for expected element to be present and it will either timeout with an error when element is not found or continue the control flow for current test only after the popup and the button shows up.

```js
var timeout = 10000; // default value for timeout
browser.wait(function () {
  return browser.isElementPresent(element(by.buttonText('CANCEL')));
}, timeout);
```

Comment: e2e.ts (75,37): Argument of type 'ElementFinder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Locator | { className: string; } | { css: string; } | { id: string; } | { js: string; } | { linkT...'.
  Type 'ElementFinder' is not assignable to type 'Function'.   @Tom Tu

Comment: Works in JS - but for TS try to change `element(by.buttonText(...))` with just `by.buttonText('CANCEL')` isElementPreset should accept ElementLocator as well and I guess your td for protractor tells it should accept just Locator and not the Element (which is not true)